# Deviation from Normality Assumptions - t-test and f-test

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, assumptions

Note that I am not a statistics major, but someone who is applying a workflow informed by statistics to a technical problem encountered at work. I've done some statistics at University, however the knowledge provided by these undergraduate courses has proved insufficient for me to continue with the statistical analysis.

I have data consisting of two sets of measurements, corresponding to the manufacturing processes A and B.

The business question being asked of me is to determine which process results in product of a higher quality.

I believe that quality in this instance means that the measurements are accurate (i.e. true and precise). Definitions of accuracy, trueness and precision from ISO-5725.

Therefore, I am investigating which process produces higher quality product. That is, the centre is what it is supposed to be, and the dispersion of the results from that centre is within the specifications required of the process.

I want to compare the centre and dispersion of two samples and ascertain whether there is a statistically significant difference between these values.
However, my initial assumption checking has indicated to me that one of these samples is not normally distributed, making the classical statistics more likely to produce a type-I error.

When the normality assumption is invalid for one of the two samples which I am comparing with one another, what procedure do I follow to continue with my statistical analysis?

Is there a non-parametric version of the t-test and f-test which I can use to test for the centres and spreads of the data I have?

Comment: When you say you want to determine which procedure is "statistically better", what do you mean? You later say you are interested in examining the accuracy and precision. To me, it sounds like you may want a confidence interval versus a significance test. Could you please provide more information.

Comment: I am trying to determine which procedure is "better", while using statistical tools to assist in that inference. I don't think that the difference between confidence intervals vs significance testing is the relevant part of the question, but could you point me towards somewhere to increase my knowledge please? If the data were normal, I would run a t test in r and get both a significance test and a confidence interval as a result.

Comment: I guess this is what I'm getting at. Say you're doing a significance test. Then you're comparing means (assuming you're doing a parametric test). So you're seeing if there is any difference between them (or if one is > or <). But with precision you may be getting at the range of values your variable of interest takes and which is smaller. Therefore, it's helpful to know what your actual concern is, i.e. what's your variable of interest and what specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is a little unclear. What data do you have, exactly? What do you mean by "better"?  What do you mean by "accuracy and precision of my data" and why do you think a measure of spread will help? Why do you want to compare means? Means of what?  And what's in the scatter plot?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, I have made some changes and hopefully clarified matters, as well as removing extraneous detail which was confusing.

Comment: Any further insight?

I've been advised that perhaps a Bayesian approach might be more suitable, rather than a frequentist approach, and been pointed in the direction of Kruschke's book and CRAN r-package.